# Irregular line spacing in parbox or minipage inside align environment using amsart

Tags: align, amsmath, minipage, amsart, parbox

When I use a `parbox` or `minipage` inside an `align` environment (from the `amsmath` package) while using the `amsart` document class, the line spacing within the `parbox` is irregular. The following example shows how, inside the `parbox` or `minipage`, two lines are set closer together if the line above contains letters with descenders and the line below contains letters with ascenders. The issue does not arise inside `equation` environments, and does not arise if I change the document class to `article`.

```
\documentclass{amsart}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

Align, parbox:
\begin{align}
\parbox{16mm}{aaaa aaaa aaaa aaaa aaaa aaaa}\qquad
\parbox{16mm}{aaaa aaap aaaa aaap aaaa aaaa}\qquad
\parbox{16mm}{aaaa aaaa aaaa aaat aaaa aaat}\qquad
\parbox{16mm}{aaaa aaap aaaa aaat aaaa aaap}\qquad
\parbox{16mm}{aaaa aaap aaap aaat aaat aaap}
\end{align}

Equation, parbox:
\begin{equation}
\parbox{16mm}{aaaa aaaa aaaa aaaa aaaa aaaa}\qquad
\parbox{16mm}{aaaa aaap aaaa aaap aaaa aaaa}\qquad
\parbox{16mm}{aaaa aaaa aaaa aaat aaaa aaat}\qquad
\parbox{16mm}{aaaa aaap aaaa aaat aaaa aaap}\qquad
\parbox{16mm}{aaaa aaap aaap aaat aaat aaap}
\end{equation}

Align, minipage:
\begin{align}
\begin{minipage}[c]{16mm}aaaa aaaa aaaa aaaa aaaa aaaa\end{minipage}\qquad
\begin{minipage}[c]{16mm}aaaa aaap aaaa aaap aaaa aaaa\end{minipage}\qquad
\begin{minipage}[c]{16mm}aaaa aaaa aaaa aaat aaaa aaat\end{minipage}\qquad
\begin{minipage}[c]{16mm}aaaa aaap aaaa aaat aaaa aaap\end{minipage}\qquad
\begin{minipage}[c]{16mm}aaaa aaap aaap aaat aaat aaap\end{minipage}
\end{align}

Equation, minipage:
\begin{equation}
\begin{minipage}[c]{16mm}aaaa aaaa aaaa aaaa aaaa aaaa\end{minipage}\qquad
\begin{minipage}[c]{16mm}aaaa aaap aaaa aaap aaaa aaaa\end{minipage}\qquad
\begin{minipage}[c]{16mm}aaaa aaaa aaaa aaat aaaa aaat\end{minipage}\qquad
\begin{minipage}[c]{16mm}aaaa aaap aaaa aaat aaaa aaap\end{minipage}\qquad
\begin{minipage}[c]{16mm}aaaa aaap aaap aaat aaat aaap\end{minipage}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Here is the output:

[image: Sample output showing line spacing issues]

How do I ensure consistent line spacing in the `parbox` or `minipage` in this context? I assume I am using them incorrectly but that coincidentally the problem does not show up when using the `article` class or `equation` environment.

(I know it is simple enough to hack around this issue by adding `\strut` in appropriate places, but I would prefer to understand the fundamental problem.)

Comment: That's ... interesting ... +1

Comment: Mostly you have problems with descenders on the last row.  Try starting and ending with a \strut.

Comment: @JohnKormylo a strut will make them all bad! It is the lines _with_ descenders or letters higher than x-height that have bad spacing, so struts don't really help here.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle - Sorry, I meant EVERY \parbox should start and stop with a \strut.   In this case, however, the middle line is messed up as well.

Comment: @JohnKormylo yes it's a latex bug really. we might fix it there. perhaps.

Comment: We have decided to fix this in the next latex release.

Comment: Fixed on 2017-03-29 in ltxboxes.dtx https://github.com/latex3/latex2e/commit/d2f762d46128bbee1e4fc6c23e9628f5f2d0c637

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{amsart}


\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

Align, parbox:
\begin{align}
\parbox{16mm}{1aaa aaaa aaaa aaaa aaaa aaaa}
\parbox{16mm}{2aaa aaap aaap aaat aaat aaap}
\end{align}

\makeatletter
\g@addto@macro\@parboxrestore{\lineskiplimit\normallineskip}
\makeatother
Align, parbox:
\begin{align}
\parbox{16mm}{1aaa aaaa aaaa aaaa aaaa aaaa}
\parbox{16mm}{2aaa aaap aaap aaat aaat aaap}
\end{align}


\end{document}
```

Inside parboxes, minipages etc LaTeX executes `\@parboxrestore` to normalise settings including `\baselineskip` and `\lineskip` which control baseline spacing however (which is arguably a bug, although it's always been that way) it does not reset `\lineskiplimit` which is the cutoff point when TeX switches to using `\lineskip`. in `amsart` this has a relatively high value of 4pt inside `align` which makes sense to keep displayed equation rows apart but the behaviour  when `\lineskip` is set back to `\normalineskip` (which is `1pt`) is never useful, `\lineskiplimit` should never be larger than `\lineskip` or, as you observe making the text in the line taller can result in *closer* line spacing.

Note that the issue is also potentially there in `article` not just `amsart`. If you add

```
\typeout{%
\the\baselineskip,
\the\lineskip,
\the\lineskiplimit
}
```

You will see

```
12.0pt, 1.0pt, 4.0pt
```

in amsart and

and

```
12.0pt, 1.0pt, 3.0pt
```

in article.

So the issue of `\lineskiplimit` being too large applies in both cases, it is just a little bit worse in `amsart` so even the modest extra height/depth of lowercase `t` and `p` are enough to trigger the effect.

`\@parboxrestore` should reset `\lineskiplimit` to `\normallineskiplimit` eg by running `\normalbaselines` but compatibility concerns may make it difficult to change this....